# manually upload differs from automatic updating

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very beginner with Java and Selenium so my apologies in advance if my question is elementary.

The story is that we have a webpage, there are two buttons in there, we need to click on one of them which is called upload to upload an excel sheet file and then we will click on the second one which parse the file and show its content on the page, the only rule is that if we have already uploaded the file, when we click on the second button it should throws an error saying that the file already exists.

I am using this code to upload the file:

```
WebElement upload = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
.xpath("//input[@type='file']")));
upload.sendKeys("C:\\test.xlsx");
```

It uploads the file, after uploading when I click on the other button it shows the error which is fine, BUT when I Do exactly the same steps manually it does not show the error!! the only difference is that while I am doing it manually, after clicking on upload button a window opens and I navigate to the excel sheet and click on open.

Comment: If you're doing exactly same things; It might not be uploading the file with Selenium, and it might getting a false-negative error.

Comment: @Turcia what is false-negative error?

Comment: what kind of error? is it a selenium error, or error coming from web site, or client-side browser error?

Comment: @KirilS. the error is coming from web site, it's designed to be this way that if you try to upload a file witch is already aploaded the website shows an error, and it happens when I run the test (which is good) but when I do it manually the error is NOT shown